# Error in Json Schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have two Requests will be either 
one with  Last Name or First Name Along with Gender and State
or thru Userid

So the request for NameSearch is either

```
{
"NameSearch":
{"LastName": "Doe",
"Gender":"Male",
"State" : "FL"
}
}

or 

{
"NameSearch":
{
"FirstName": "John",
"Gender":"Male",
"State" : "FL"
}
}
```

and for UseridSearch is as follows

```
{
"UIDSearch":
{
"UID": "12345"
}
}
```

I wrote a schema to validate this to accomadate all three type of requests

```
{
     "anyOf": [

     {
    "type":"object",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties":{


        "NameSearch": {         
    "anyOf": 
        [
            {
                "type":"object",
                "additionalProperties": false,
                "properties":
                                {
                                    "FirstName": 
                                        {
                                            "type":"string",                                          
                                            "required":true
                                        },

                                    "Gender": 
                                        {
                                            "type":"string",                                    
                                            "required":true
                                        },
                                    "State": 
                                        {
                                            "type":"string",
                                            "required":true
                                        }
                                }
            },
            {
                "additionalProperties": false,
                "properties":
                                {
                                    "LastName": 
                                        {
                                            "type":"string",                                          
                                            "required":true
                                        },

                                    "Gender": 
                                        {
                                            "type":"string",                                    
                                            "required":true
                                        },
                                    "State": 
                                        {
                                            "type":"string",
                                            "required":true
                                        }
                                }
            }
        ]
 }
 }
 },

         {
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "properties":{
        "UIDSearch": {
            "type":"object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties":{
                                    "UID": 
                                        {
                                            "type":"string",
                                            "required":true
                                        }
                        }
                    }
                    }
                    }

                    ]
                    }
```

But SchemaValidator says invalid. Could you point me where is my error and is there any way to make the schema small

Comment: have you tried jsonlint.com for valididty?

Comment: I tried to validate my request against schema  in json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com. But got the errors

Comment: what error are you exactly getting , jsonlint.com says it's valid json

Comment: this is json draft v4. but our validator doesn't support it seems. So we need to do it draftv3

Answer (score 0):

I might be late, but I think you have forgotten to add "type":"object" in the schema you defined for the JSON in which last name is given as input

so you final schema would be

```
{
 "anyOf": [

 {
"type":"object",
"additionalProperties": false,
"properties":{


    "NameSearch": {         
"anyOf": 
    [
        {
            "type":"object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties":
                            {
                                "FirstName": 
                                    {
                                        "type":"string",                                          
                                        "required":true
                                    },

                                "Gender": 
                                    {
                                        "type":"string",                                    
                                        "required":true
                                    },
                                "State": 
                                    {
                                        "type":"string",
                                        "required":true
                                    }
                            }
        },
        {
            "type":"object",       //changed here
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties":
                            {
                                "LastName": 
                                    {
                                        "type":"string",                                          
                                        "required":true
                                    },

                                "Gender": 
                                    {
                                        "type":"string",                                    
                                        "required":true
                                    },
                                "State": 
                                    {
                                        "type":"string",
                                        "required":true
                                    }
                            }
        }
    ]
 }
 }
 },

     {
"additionalProperties": false,
"properties":{
    "UIDSearch": {
        "type":"object",
        "additionalProperties": false,
        "properties":{
                                "UID": 
                                    {
                                        "type":"string",
                                        "required":true
                                    }
                    }
                }
                }
                }

                ]
                }
```

Comment: anything in draft3 version. as anyOf is supported only in draft4